# How to disable tabs from activities inside tabs in android using onclick button event?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

My application has a TabActivity which contains 5 tabs. Each tab contains the corresponding form filling activities.

The activity in the first tab is the form  Activity. when user submit form and Click "Submit" button then and then new activity should enable.Based on some conditions I have to enable/disable the other 4 tabs from this Activity.

Can anyone help in enabling/disabling tabs from activities inside the tab?

Comment: "Each tab contains the corresponding form filling activities" -- this technique has been deprecated for over two years.

Comment: I mean to say activity is "form" when user fill the form and click on submit button then an then new activity will get enable